# How to construct a natural deduction proof for the following question

Tags: proof-writing

Hi I have been trying this question for a while but I'm unable to construct a proof for the following question, these rules I have proved and these can be used in the proof any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It is good to show what you have tried

Comment: What does DM stand for?

Comment: @FShrike From the looks of it, it looks like DM stands for DeMorgan's law

Comment: Please don't change the question after people answered it. That's a rude way to thank them for their time and efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the "additional" rules (that are not part of the standard [ND set of rules](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4)) we have:

1. $(p \land q) \to r$ --- premise
2. $\lnot [(p \to r) \lor (q \to r)]$ - assumed [a]
3. $\lnot (p \to r) \land \lnot (q \to r)$ --- from 2) by (DM)
4. $\lnot (p \to r)$ --- from 3)
5. $(p \land \lnot r)$ --- from 4) by (NoI)
6. $p$ --- from 5)
7. $\lnot r$ --- from 5)
8. $\lnot (q \to r)$ --- from 3)
9. $(q \land \lnot r)$ --- from 8) by (NoI)
10. $q$ --- from 9)
11. $(p \land q)$ --- from 6) and 10)
12. $r$ --- from 1) and 11)
13. $\bot$ --- Contradiction, from 7) and 12)

> 14. $(p \to r) \lor (q \to r)$ --- from 2) and 13) by Double Negation, discharging [a]